# How add gradient to stroke

Tags: android, xml, colors, gradient

I can not add gradient to stroke in my shape for image view.

My shape:

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
     <padding 
        android:bottom="0dp" />
     <corners android:radius="6dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="6dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp" 
  android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="6dp"/> 
     <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

How `andorid:color=ffffff" />` change to gradient.

My code for layout

```
        <ImageView
            p1:id="@+id/imgArticle"
            p1:layout_width="50dp"
            p1:layout_height="50dp"
            p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            p1:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            p1:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <ImageView
            p1:src="@drawable/radiusarticleimage"
            p1:id="@+id/imgShape"
            p1:background="@android:color/transparent"
            p1:layout_width="55dp"
            p1:layout_height="55dp"
            p1:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
```

This is my current result[image]

I want to change the white border around the image to be a gradient.

Comment: You could use a LayerList. Make a (bigger) rectangle filled with a gradient. Then add another (smaller) rectangle filled in a solid color.

Comment: My first ImageView is photo, i must have border with gradient color http://s28.postimg.org/r7dr7rrwd/article.jpg . how change white color with gradient ,pls example

Comment: I would use canvas. What kind of gradient you want, linear?

Comment: Vertical , As with the background in the image <gradient
        android:startColor="#b3b3b3"
        android:endColor="#e6e6e6"
        android:angle="90"/>

Comment: Well LayerLists can include images as well. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList